# Backspace in replace

Tags: regex

I need to backspace when I replace in a regex sentence in notepad+/sublimetext3.

I have this text.

> ¿Qué pasa si se formatea una computadora?
>
> Formatear es reducir un disco duro a la configuración inicial, al
> estado de fábrica, dejando la unidad totalmente limpia para instalar
> en ella cualquier cosa. Lo que se hace, pues, es prepararlo para que
> el ordenador en el que funcione tenga el software y los archivos que
> tu quieras y como lo quieras.
>
> ¿Qué pasa si le doy a formatear el disco duro?
>
> Al formatear un disco duro, sea nuevo o no, se crea una partición de
> arranque, donde se encontrará instalado el sistema operativo. La
> unidad q1ue se formatea puede ser usada como disco duro maestro (o
> esclavo), y permite ser leído y escrito un gran número de veces.

And I use that for search and replace

Search: `(^[^?]*\?\s*)([^.]+\.)`

Replace: `$1<b>$2</b>`

And put the bold to the first sentence, but I need a backspace to put the text like that

> ¿Qué pasa si se formatea una computadora? **Formatear es reducir un disco duro a la configuración inicial, al estado de fábrica, dejando la unidad totalmente limpia para instalar en ella cualquier cosa.** Lo que se hace, pues, es prepararlo para que el ordenador en el que funcione tenga el software y los archivos que tu quieras y como lo quieras.

> ¿Qué pasa si le doy a formatear el disco duro? **Al formatear un disco duro, sea nuevo o no, se crea una partición de arranque, donde se encontrará instalado el sistema operativo.** La unidad q1ue se formatea puede ser usada como disco duro maestro (o esclavo), y permite ser leído y escrito un gran número de veces.

How can I do?

EDIT: I need one more thing.

When i have this text how can select the the first line since firt to the question and do that

✔ ¿Cómo se hace para formatear una PC? **Para restablecer el equipo, ve a Inicio > Configuración > Sistema > Recuperación .** Junto a Restablecer este equipo, selecciona Restablecer equipo.

✔ ¿Cómo formatear mi PC windows 10 a estado de fábrica? **Haz click sobre el botón de inicio.** Selecciona la rueda dentada para acceder a Ajustes del Sistema. Pulsa sobre Actualización y Seguridad. En la pestaña de Restaurar, haz click en Comenzar o Empezar. En la ventana que se abre, selecciona Restablecer Ajustes de. Fábrica.

FINAL TEXT

¿Cómo se hace para formatear una PC?

**✔ ¿Cómo se hace para formatear una PC?** **Para restablecer el equipo, ve a Inicio > Configuración > Sistema > Recuperación .** Junto a Restablecer este equipo, selecciona Restablecer equipo.

✔ ¿Cómo formatear mi PC windows 10 a estado de fábrica? **Haz click sobre el botón de inicio.** Selecciona la rueda dentada para acceder a Ajustes del Sistema. Pulsa sobre Actualización y Seguridad. En la pestaña de Restaurar, haz click en Comenzar o Empezar. En la ventana que se abre, selecciona Restablecer Ajustes de. Fábrica.

Comment: i update the question with another dude, best regards.

Comment: *"with another dude"*: huh? *"I need one more thing."*: a question should be *one* question only.

Answer (score -2):

i think i solve that with this

Search `\A^&#10004; (.*\?)`

Replace `$1\n\n<b>$1. </b>`

thank you.